# Cast select column to date in view to then run query against

Tags: sql-server

I have a view where I Select about 100 rows to allow users to easily query data.  In this data, I have a field that is sometimes a date and sometimes text.  A date or text depends on type.  I cast to a date value like so.

```
SELECT Cast(Value as Date) as column 
from Table
Where type = 1
```

When you then try to run a query against this column, you get a Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.  Here is the query.

```
 SELECT Column 
 From View 
 WHERE Column BETWEEN '01/01/2015'  AND '12/31/2015'
```

I have another field that is a date and if I replace it in this query, the query works.  Likewise the data from the whole table will load.  Any ideas are appreciated.  Thanks

Basically, I need this Query to work and not give me the error described above.

```
select cast(value as date) 
from Value
where type = 1
and cast(value as date) between '01/01/2015' and '12/31/2015'
```

Comment: try running 'Select * from table where isdate(value) = 0'

Comment: Do you have any indexes on the table?

Comment: Just the PK (Clustered) index

Comment: Which I'm assuming is not on the date, right?

Comment: Correct.  I also removed it and got the same error.

Comment: does the view have the TOP built in?

Comment: No.  It selects everything where the type is 1 like the query I wrote in my edit to the question.  Both exhibit the same behavior.  If we can fix the query then it will most likely fix the view also and makes the question a bit easier to explain.

Comment: Only other thing I can think to try is run it with "include actual execution plan" turned on and see if it is trying to check the date column before the type, but I'm grasping at this point as I can't duplicate the error

Comment: Ok, I will try that this weekend.  Thanks for your thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you have entries in that column that cannot be converted to datetime.  You may be able to find them by running

```
Select * from table where isdate(value) = 0
```

Comment: I am able to run (Select * from table)  If I had entries that couldn't be converted then that would error out.  Also when I run that I get the following error.  "Argument data type date is invalid for argument 1 of isdate function."

Comment: Why would Select * from Table error out just because a column had entries that couldn't be converted to datetime?

Comment: If I did select * on a view that was converting that column data to a date it would error if it couldn't convert it.

Comment: Just ran your query and had no results come back with the query.

Comment: But select * from table is not the same thing as select * from view

Comment: The table has values that are not dates.  It is a string field that has dates if the type is 1 and text if type is 2, so if I do the query on the table lots of rows will come back as not dates.  When I select the column, I am only selecting it with a type of 1.

Comment: Also, I'm not sure it would.  If the view is limited to 100 and the errors are not within the first 100.  Guessing here

Comment: that is information that should be in your question